# My code is showing no errmsg but is not inserting any data into database

Tags: php, mysql

So I am trying to make a simple e-commerce site. Once I submit the form (btn-submit), I am not able to insert any data to my database. Only the address and contact number verification works.

Here is my code:

```
    if ( isset($_POST['btn-submit']) ) {

    // clean user inputs 
    $oadd = trim($_POST['oadd']);
    $oadd = strip_tags($oadd);
    $oadd = htmlspecialchars($oadd);

    $contact = trim($_POST['contact']);
    $contact = strip_tags($contact);
    $contact = htmlspecialchars($contact);


    // address validation
    if (empty($oadd)) {
        $error = true;
        $oaddError = "Please enter a valid address.";
    } else if (strlen($oadd) < 5) {
        $error = true;
        $oaddError = "Please enter a valid address.";
    }

    // contact number validation
    if (empty($contact)) {
        $error = true;
        $contactError = "Please enter your contact number.";
    } else if (strlen($contact) < 7) {
        $error = true;
        $contactError = "Contact number must have atleast 7 digits.";
    } else if (!preg_match("/^[0-9 ]+$/",$lname)) {
        $error = true;
        $lnameError = "Please enter a valid contact number.";
    }

    // if there's no error, continue to place order
    if( !$error ) {
        $query = 'INSERT INTO cust_order(Order_Date, Order_Status, Order_Total , Address, Contact_No) VALUES (CURDATE(), "in process" , (SELECT SUM(p.Product_Price) FROM cart c, product p WHERE c.Prod_ID = p.Product_ID and c. User_ID = "'.$userRow['User_ID'].'"),"'.$oadd.'","'. $contact.'")';
        $res = mysql_query($query);

        if ($res) {
            $errTyp = "success";
            $errMSG = "Your order has been placed. To view the details, go to your order history";
            unset($oadd);
            unset($contact);
        } else {
            $errTyp = "danger";
            $errMSG = "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";   
        }   

    }

}
```

What could possibly be wrong with my code? I did similar queries in the other pages but this is the only one not working. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: `$userRow['User_ID']` I don't find the value of userRow?

Comment: sorry. here's my code before the one above

$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE User_ID=".$_SESSION['user']);
    $userid=$_SESSION['user'];
    $userRow=mysql_fetch_array($res);

    $error = false;

    if ( isset($_POST['btn-submit']) ) {

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Your user data is **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) and there are [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) and can be exploited.

Comment: **WARNING**: `strip_tags` and `htmlspecialchars` are **NOT** suitable escaping functions. If you're stuck using the obsolete `mysql_query` system, use `mysql_real_escape_string` on **any and all** user data.

Comment: This code will never show error messages because you need to check for errors, then find out what error happened by asking. This is why `mysql_query` is junk. Newer interfaces like PDO can raise exceptions so you won't be left wondering what went wrong.

Comment: @tadman Thanks for the advice. I'll take note of them. Anyway, I'll try to fix my code first and see if there will be improvements. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to understand the code flow:

```
if( !$error ) {
    // This will only works when **$error is false and the not of false is true**, otherwise this block does not execute
}
```

So this code works only when there is no validation error occurs in your code and `$error` contains `false`

Comment: So stupid of me to not notice this part. You're right. I just removed it and everything worked. Thank you @Mayank and thanks everyone. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
//$userRow is not define any where...
//to check error occur or not :
echo $error;
if(!$error)
{
    echo "IN IF";
    //also go with die..
    $res = mysql_query($query) or die();
}
else
{
    echo "IN ELSE";
}
```